# Should socket.io socket IDs be kept secret?

Tags: socket.io

Let's say I'm making a server that allows anonymous users to join.

If I want to enable private messaging between two users, is it safe to broadcast everyone's socket ID who is currently connected?

Or should I generate another identifier and broadcast that?

Comment: I'm asking myself the same question right now... Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I didn't no. I ended up not having private messaging, and instead the only user-to-user message than was needed was 'game-invite' so keeping it a secret wasn't an issue.

Comment: Same question answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600057/should-the-socket-io-socket-id-be-secret

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should the socket.io socket ID be secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600057/should-the-socket-io-socket-id-be-secret)